# Is there a way to use date instead of datetime in d3blocks movingbubbles?

Tags: python, d3.js

How can I use date instead of datetime in d3blocks movingbubbles?

I have a column with date instead of datetime. I have converted it to datetime and used it to make a d3blocks movingbubbles visualization. However, I would like to use the date argument and not datetime.

I tried the code below

```
#Input parameters.
d3.movingbubbles(attendance,
                 datetime='datetime',
                 sample_id='sample_id',
                 state='state',
                 #center='Travel',
                 standardize=None,
                 damper=1,
                 fontsize=14,
                 #reset_time='day',
                 speed={"slow": 4000, "medium": 2000, "fast": 5},
                 figsize=(780, 800),
                 note=None,
                 title='d3blocks_movingbubbles',
                 filepath='movingbubbles.html',
                 showfig=True,
                 overwrite=True)
```

which resulted in the following output

[image: current output]

However, I would like the top left to display the date like this expected output:

[image: expected output]